# custom instance method in Angular $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

all actions for a AngularJS `$resource` are added as `$customAction` methods to the Resource so that I can invoke them as methods on resource instances, e.g.:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.get({userId:123}, function(user) {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
});
```

`$save` is the `save` action and can be called on the `user` instance.

I now defined the following custom action, leading to a `$attributes` method on every instance of `user`:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'}, {
  attributes: { method: 'GET', url: '/user/:userId/attributes', isArray: true }
});
```

If I now try to invoke this method, I get the error `Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'`:

```
User.get({userId:123}, function(user) {
  var attrs = user.$attributes();    // error
  // ...
});
```

Did I get the concept of custom actions wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eventual solution for me was to switch to [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular). It supports nested resources using a chaining syntax so that I can to the following:

`Restangular.one("user", 123).all("attributes").get()`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you should use params instead of url

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId/:customAction', {userId:'@id'}, {
  attributes: { method: 'GET', params: { userId:'@id', customAction: 'attributes'}, isArray: true }
});
```